# Gridview.builder doesn't update by setState()

Tags: flutter, gridview, set, state, setstate

I am creating dynamic widget from a list and When I clicked the  widget that created by list I want it to update its name. I am using stateful widget and there is no error, when I click the widget suggestionList updating itself but it doesn't effect the Text widget.

This is my list

```
List suggestionList = [
{'name':'Tomato','imageurl':'https://ayb.akinoncdn.com/products/2021/06/18/7025/46ead09c-f4cb- 
4b85-acd7-8ca1d8452864_size780x780_quality60_cropCenter.jpg'}];
```

This is my GridView

```
 GridView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: suggestionList.length,
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
     crossAxisCount: 2,
  ),
     itemBuilder: (context,index){
     Map data = suggestionList[index];
     return GestureDetector(
     onTap: (){
     setState(() {
          suggestionList.clear();
          suggestionList = 
   
   
 [{'name':'Eggplant','imageurl':'https://ayb.akinoncdn.com/products/2021/06/18/7025/46ead09c- 
 f4cb-4b85-acd7-8ca1d8452864_size780x780_quality60_cropCenter.jpg'}];
        print(suggestionList);
        });
   },
child:Container(

  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
          boxShadow: [
  BoxShadow(
    color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.05),
    blurRadius: 2.0, // soften the shadow
    spreadRadius: 1.0, //extend the shadow
    offset: Offset(
      0, // Move to right 10  horizontally
      1.0, // Move to bottom 5 Vertically
    ),
  )
],
            


),
  child: Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          flex: 10,
          child: Container(
          
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
          
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
         
            
  image: DecorationImage(image: NetworkImage(data['imageurl']),
  fit: BoxFit.scaleDown)
),
          
        ),),
       
        Expanded(flex:1,
        child: Text(data['name'],style: TextStyle(
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600
        ),),),
      ],
    ),
  
));}
),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone need it, I am putting the answer here. I am using state management now and it works like a charm.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget{
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context){
return MultiProvider(
  child: MaterialApp(
    title: 'Provider',
    home: NewMainPage(),
  ),
  providers: [
    ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: PageState()),
  ],
);
}
}

 class PageState extends ChangeNotifier{
 var suggestionList = [

 {'name':'Domates','imageurl':'
       https://ayb.akinoncdn.com/products/2021/06/18/7025/46e
       ad09c-f4cb-4b85-acd7-8ca1d8452864_size780x780_quality60_cropCenter.jpg'},
{'name':'Biber','imageurl':'
       https://iasbh.tmgrup.com.tr/d852d6/1200/627/0/187/800/604? 
       u=https://isbh.tmgrup.com.tr/sbh/2020/05/14/biberin-faydalari-nelerdir- 
       yesil-biberin-cilde-faydalari-1589469175731.jpg'},
{'name':'Patlıcan','imageurl':'
     https://cdn.cimri.io/market/260x260/patlican-_210439.jpg'},
  ];
add(List a){
suggestionList = a.toList();
notifyListeners();
 }
}

 class NewMainPage extends StatelessWidget {

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 List suggestionList = Provider.of<PageState>(context).suggestionList;
 // TODO: implement build
 return Scaffold(
 appBar: AppBar(
   title: Text('Provider'),),
   body: GridView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
 itemCount: Provider.of<PageState>(context).suggestionList.length,
 gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
 crossAxisCount: 2,
 ),
 itemBuilder: (context,index){
 Map data = Provider.of<PageState>(context).suggestionList[index];
 return GestureDetector(
onTap: (){
  
  Provider.of<PageState>(context,listen:false).add([{'name':'Eggplant','imageurl':'https://ayb.akinoncdn.com/products/2021/06/18/7025/46ead09c-f4cb-4b85-acd7-8ca1d8452864_size780x780_quality60_cropCenter.jpg'}].toList());
},
child:Container(

  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
          boxShadow: [
  BoxShadow(
    color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.05),
    blurRadius: 2.0, // soften the shadow
    spreadRadius: 1.0, //extend the shadow
    offset: Offset(
      0, // Move to right 10  horizontally
      1.0, // Move to bottom 5 Vertically
    ),
  )
],
            


),
  child: Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          flex: 10,
          child: Container(
          
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
          
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
         
            
  image: DecorationImage(image: NetworkImage(data['imageurl']),
  fit: BoxFit.scaleDown)
),
          
        ),),
       
        Expanded(flex:1,
        child: Text(data['name'],style: TextStyle(
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600
        ),),),
      ],
    ),
  
 ));}
   ),

 );
 }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
    setState(() {
      suggestionList.clear();
      suggestionList= List.from(suggestionList)
       ..add({'name':'Eggplant','imageurl':'https://ayb.akinoncdn.com/products/2021/06/18/7025/46ead09c- 
 f4cb-4b85-acd7-8ca1d8452864_size780x780_quality60_cropCenter.jpg'});
    });
```

Comment: Well it doesn't work but thank you for the care. I am using state management now and it works like a charm thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This problem happen when you try to create list inside `Widget build(BuildContext context) {}` function, so **do not** fill your list inside this function like this:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 List suggestionList = Provider.of<PageState>(context).suggestionList; // here your problem, this is wrong way
}
```

The correct way that does not cause problems is fill your `List` inside `initState()` function like this:

```
  final List _suggestionList = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _suggestionList.add('value'); // here fill your list

  }
```

So if you use code in this correct way you will not need `provider` package.